# SharePoint Custom WorkFlow + "Path needs to point to valid member"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I have developed a custom workflow using following link :- " http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2011/03/30/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-sequential-workflow-with-a-custom-task-form-in-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010-part-2-of-2/#comment-52198 ".

but when i try to deploy the solution, its shows error on the workflow designer and it gets deployed. but it doesn't create the workflow.

Error :-

for each activity its shows :-

```
Path 'RW_Taskid" used to specify members for "workflow 1" is invalid. Path needs to point to valid members.
```

please help me with the same.

thanx, 
Nidhi Mohan

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can find two links for your refenrece may it helps you

1. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab403fdf-0985-4922-9443-99cfe83c112c/error-path-needs-to-point-to-valid-member?forum=windowsworkflowfoundation
2. http://spnovice.blogspot.com/2012/12/spd-workflow-error-path-needs-to-point.html

First link says that all the variables you delcare should be Public instead of protected and 
Second link says about missing the type.

In Your case its **"RW_Taskid"**. So if you have a backup of your workflow then you can give this a try

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, But i have already seen these links. Its not working for me, more over the workflow is declared as " public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);" in my solution. i am not sure what has to changed to make it public and how to bind it to the public rapper. Regards.